# web3.js can I call a smart contract function without knowing the ABI?

Tags: web3js, tokens, addresses, metamask

In a web3 JS dApp (eg.with Metamask),
If I know just the *address* of a contract and the *method name*, how can I call that method ?

I don't know the ABI.

Comment: This can be done if you know the method *signature* (including the types of the parameters), but not with just the name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm posting a proper answer here - thanks to @smarx, and others off SO who helped lead me to this solution.

## The answer

> This can be done if you know the method *signature* (including the types
> of the parameters), but not with just the name. – @smarx

---

### ERC20 example - show balance of any token

So, for example, an [ERC20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) compliant token contract will implement a `balanceOf()` method.
The *signature* of that method looks like this (see below for how to obtain that) :

```
var abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
```

Now get the contract address of the tokens you are interested in.
As an example, on the **Ropsten** network, there is a Panda Token contract at *0x45135b8ED5f52528175CCC6D7add2228779eDeE0* (donate Ropsten ETH [here](http://krisrandall.github.io/panda-tokens/index.html) to receive some Panda Tokens), so you can see your Panda Token balance with the following code (in addition to the abi line above):

```
var tokenContractAddress = "0x45135b8ED5f52528175CCC6D7add2228779eDeE0"
var contract = web3.eth.contract( abi ).at( tokenContractAddress )
var account 
web3.eth.getAccounts( (err, ok) => account = ok[0] )
// wait for account to be set ...
contract.balanceOf( account, function(err,ok) { console.log(err,ok.c[0]) } )
```

---

#### How to get the ERC20 `balanceOf()` *signature*

To obtain the *signature* of this method, I simply went to Remix, and pasted in the following as the contract (having obtained the function definition from the [ERC20 definition](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard)):

```
contract ERC20 {
      function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance);
}
```

Then go to *Compile* > *Details* > *INTERFACE - ABI* (Copy)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the ABI or the bytecode (so if you don't have the contract code), **you cannot** send trasanction(s) or call(s).

But if you know it, in web3js 1.0.0-beta, just do:

```
contractInstance.methods.getBalance().call(address, function(result){
//do something with the variable
});
```

Or, for a transaction:

```
contractInstance.methods.setBalance(address).send({from: someone}, function(hash){
//dosomething
});
```

---

Edit for comments: How to create the contractInstance

```
if (contractInstance == null || contractInstance == 'undefined') {
        console.log("Making a new contract instance");
        var code = fs.readFileSync(solidityFile).toString();
        // Compile the contract code
        var compiledCode = solc.compile(code);
        //Generate the ABI 
        abi = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':NAMEOFYOUCONTRACT'].interface);
        contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
        console.log("Contract instance created successfully");
```

Comment: how are you instantiating `contractInstance` in the sample code in your answer?  can it be created without the ABI?

Comment: I updated the answer. And as I said in it, no, you cannot if you don't have the ABI or the bytecode

Comment: How does OpenSea call the NFT methods on an ERC-721 contract that has not published the code then?

Comment: I have not checked that. However, ERC being a standard, one could probably generate the ABI. (pure speculation). Moreover, note that this answer is 5 years old and things may (and probably have) changed).

Answer (score 0):

please note the length of args the function takes must be known
args is a list of the data structures the function takes. for
example: ["address","bool"]

if you are unsure of the type use "int"

```
const genericABIGenerator = (
  args,
  function_name,
  returnType = "int"
) => {
  return [
    {
      inputs: args.map((value, index) => ({
        name: `arg${index}`,
        type: value ?? "int",
      })),
      name: function_name,
      outputs: [
        {
          name: "output",
          type: returnType,
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
  ];
};
```

code execution

```
const contract = new client.eth.Contract(
    genericABIGenerator(inputTypeList, function_name, outputType),
    contractAddress
  );
const result = await contract.methods[function_name](...args).call();
```

Answer (score 0):

> somehow the answers all assume you know the method name and arguments

How to call a smart contract method if you **indeed do not know** the **method name**?

1. Decompile the contract, e.g. https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0xcbb011006eadd48a241eca39181be7834b93dd0b
2. *You'll get meaningful names for some methods, as the decompiler has a massive dictionary of known methods and their signatures. So here you know the ABI*
3. Other methods do not have names, but you will get their signatures and arguments, something like

```py
def unknownb2b958b8(uint256 _param1)
```

To call this method, we use a workaround - we set the `signature` field of the methods ABI manually, after the `Contract` instance is created, as `web3js` calculates the signatures in the constructor.

```typescript
let methodAbi = {
    type: 'function',
    name: 'someMethod',
    inputs: [ { 'type': 'uint256' } ]
};
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract([ methodAbi ], '0x...');

// web3.js in constructor calculates the method signature, but we have to reset it mannually
methodAbi.signature = '0x2b958b8';


// now we use 'someMethod' name to call or send to the 0x2b958b8 method

let paramExample = 5;
let result = await contract.methods.someMethod(paramExample).call();
```

> If the parameters are of complex types, like `struct`, in the decompiled method, you could see just the `array` as a type for that parameter, so you have to dig deeper into the code or other transactions input data to find out the types of the parameters